# angularjs - can't display json data on a specific page

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-http

I'm trying to load data from JSON-file and displaying in my mobile app. But the problem is that I can't display the JSON datas on member-detail.html, where should be displayed datas of a specific user. But on member-index.html, where is the whole list of all users, I can get the json datas correctly.

I've two pages/templates:

- **member-index.html**: List with all members. Linked to the member-detail.html. JSON data are displayed correctly here:
- **member-detail.html**: detail information about a single member. JSON data are **not displayed correctly**. On this page I actually only try to output following two expressions:

  ```
      <h2>Name: {{member.firstname }} {{member.lastname}}</h2>
  ```

Here you can take a look at my file /data/members.json:

```
[            
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "lastname": "Doe", 
            "firstname": "John", 
        }
  ]
```

I'm load the json data with a service about the $http.get function in file services.js. There are also two methods -> findAll for member-index.html (=is working correctly) and findById -> for member-detail.html (is working not correctly, access to json object does not working, look at this line: var member = members[memberId - 1]):

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])

.factory('MemberService', function($http, $q) {

var members = $http.get("data/members.json").success(function(result){
  return result.data;

});

return {
  findAll: function() {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    deffered.resolve(members);
    return deffered.promise;
  },
  findById: function(memberId) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //members[memberId - 1] --> THIS IS NOT WORKING
    var member = members[memberId - 1];
    deferred.resolve(member);
    return deferred.promise;
  },
}

});
```

Following controllers are used for member-detail.html:

```
.controller('MemberDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, MemberService) {
 MemberService.findById($stateParams.memberId).then(function (member) {
        $scope.member = member;
    });
```

Result of my debbuging work is, that problem is on access to JSON-object in services.js on findById method. It's following line:

- var member = members[memberId - 1]; --> it returns a undefiend

But I've no idea how I access the members variable correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find proper user by id in your `members` array using `forEach`:

```
var member = {};

angular.forEach(members, function (item) {
    if ( item.id == memberId ) {
        member =  item;
        return;
    }
});

deferred.resolve(member);

return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: Hi @artem-petrosian, thanks for your feedback. For me it does not work correctly, but maybe I understood something wrong. I tried it out like this:

Comment: @mbppv That is really strange, did you checked that `memberId` value is passed properly?

Comment: Hi @artem-petrosian, yes, memberId value is passed properly. I set up your suggestion like this:

     var members = $http.get("data/members.json");
     var member = {};

    return {
      findById: function(memberId) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        angular.forEach(members, function(item, memberId) {
          if ( item.id == memberId ) {
              member = item;
              return;
          }
        });
        deferred.resolve(member);
        return deferred.promise;
      }

Comment: @mbppv You should remove or rename the second param in your `forEach`, because you override `memberId` with item index. I've updated an example.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But it does not work for me. I'll check later whether I can find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With following code it is possible to display specific member datas in member-detail.html:

**services.js**

```
module.factory('MemberService', function($http, $q) {

  var members =  $http.get("data/members.json");

  return {
    getAll: function(){
        members = members.then(function(result){
        return result;
      })
      var deffered = $q.defer();
      deffered.resolve(members);
      return deffered.promise;
    },
  }
});
```

MemberService get members datas and return all of these datas in getAll method.

**controllers.js**

```
MemberService.getAll().then(function(members){
        angular.forEach(members.data, function(item){
          if (item.id == $stateParams.memberId){
            $scope.member = item;
          }
        })
     });
```

For each member object it will check whether item.id is same value as $stateParams.memberId, if it's true member data will loaded in $scope.member.

Thanks to @artem-petrosian for great hint.

Comment: If his answer was that useful you should consider giving him an upvote